# Updating table inside UpdatePanel

Tags: updatepanel, updateprogress

in my code i have a table inside an updatepanel with a button to update this table.
I put an updateprogress that showing "working".

The table , when i click button, will be filled from code behind with values, but when the script end, the table still empty.

If i remove the updateprogress the table will be updated..

Example code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="uppanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Table><asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell runat="server" id="value"></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table>
<asp:Button onClick="update_click" runat="server">
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress  id="updateProgress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="uppanel" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
        <span style="border-width: 0px; position: fixed; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 36px; left: 40%; top: 40%;">Loading ...</span>
    </div>
</ProgressTemplate>
```

Comment: do yo have the AssociatedUpdatePanelID attribute on your UpdateProgress control?

Comment: Yes is associated as example

Comment: can you also post your update_click code

Comment: I found my error... multiple ID with same name on tablecell